# Undefined is not a object in this.state - ReactNative

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm new in `ReactNative`, I'm getting the error `undefined is not a object` in my `this.state.rows` I am trying to dynamically add a `View` when a user clicks a `Button`. I tried using  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524026/react-native-dynamically-add-element-to-dom-on-button-press) and instead of using `getInitialState` I used `constructor(props)` but I keep on having the said error. Here is my code

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  rows: [],
};
}

addRow(){
this.state.rows.push(index++)
this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows })
}

render(){

let contactView = () => {
    return <View>
              <AddComponent />
           </View>
}

return(
 <View>
      <View>
        {contactView}
      </View>

      <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.addRow } >
        <Text>Add</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to bind `this` to the function addRow like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.addRow.bind(this) } >
  <Text>Add</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

or create an anonymous function to automatically bind this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.addRow() } >
  <Text>Add</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

For explanation refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: my error is solved. I think I just need to adjust on how will the `View` will add and displayed because it doesn't display when I clicked the button. Thank you.

Comment: The arrow function worked for me.  Previously I had `<TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.myFunction }>` but I needed to do `<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.myFunction() }>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too.

```
export default class CustomCard extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.functionName= this.handleUpvote.bind(this);
    }
}
```

For calling the function you can call it like this.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.functionName} >
  <Text>Add</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.addRow.bind(this) } >
  <Text>some text</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please provide some context to your answer and why it's the right answer