# TypeError: undefined is not an object in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm really new to Javascript and ReactJS, and am baffled by the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state = { destination: '' }')`

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor() {
        /*
        this.state = {
            destination: ''
        };
        */
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

This code works fine. But as soon as I uncomment

```
this.state = {
            destination: ''
        };
```

I get the error. Why is it bugging me about it being `undefined`? I'm not accessing it anywhere.

This might look like a duplicate of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039719/undefined-is-not-a-object-in-this-state-reactnative)
but the difference is that in that question, the solution involves using `.bind(this)` on a function the asker defined. I have no such function I can call this on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be a very misleading error caused by the fact that you try to define `this.state` before calling `super()`. `this` is not available in the constructor before `super()` has been called. You should also take the `props` argument in the constructor and pass it on to `super`, i.e. `constructor(props) { super(props); ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is configured by `super`. Before `super` is executed, `this` is not configured yet. This is the reason of the problem you have experienced. Fix:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        destination: ''
    };
}
```